# VBA Copy and Pasting 2 Rows Down

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I've only just come across VBA so I'm a complete novice. Essentially I'm currently automating a form that requires writing out the questions, potential answers, instructions, etc. for developers on a spreadsheet. I've created a basic template table so all the questions are structured the same. I want to copy and paste this table (clearing the contents and taking off the number of the question) and paste it 2 rows down from the bottom of the last table.

The code works fine if I just wanted to copy and paste the table directly below the first but I can't go any further than that. I'm not sure how to write that I want it to find the last filled in row and paste the table 2 rows below.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Range("C2:G6").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C"

    Range("A2:G6").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

You can completely avoid using `select` in order to achieve your goal. In the following code, `Source` is the range of your table, `LastRow` finds the last row of your table and `DestRng` is the destination where you want a copy of your table. Hope this helps!

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
    Dim TblRng As Range
    Set TblRng = Range("C2:G6")
    TblRng.ClearContents

    Dim Source As Range
    Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(("A2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    Source.Copy

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DestRng As Range
    Set DestRng = Source(LastRow + 1, "A")
    DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```